# how to call the data of a schema which is inside another schema(mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

I have ExerciseSchema which is inside user schema. I need to call all user data of userschema and all data fields of excersise schema except one field by finding UserId. I have done as below.

my schemas,

```
  const exerciseSchema = new Schema({
  description: String,
  duration: Number,
  date: Date
});

const Exercise = mongoose.model("Exercise", exerciseSchema);

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, unique: true },
  logs: [exerciseSchema]
});
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

my api,

```
app.get("/api/users/:_id/logs", (req, res) => {
 

  let _id = req.params._id;
  User.findById(_id, (err, data) => {
    if (!err) {
      data.count = data.logs.length;
      res.json({
        username: data.username,
        _id: data._id,
        count: data.count,
        log: data.logs
        
      })
      
    
      }
  
               })
})
```

and my return should be as follow.

```
{
  username: "test",
  count: 1,
  _id: "5fb5853f734231456ccb3b05",
  log: [{
    description: "test",
    duration: 60,
    date: "Mon Jan 01 1990",
  }]
}
```

but my return is below

```
    {
"username":"imangi",
"_id":"61795a3f15a4944e134393a4",
"count":3,"log":[{"description":"tennis",
"duration":30,
"date":2021-03-15T00:00:00.000Z,
"_id":"61795a5315a4944e134393a6"}
]}
```

all I need to do is get rid of Id and trun the date to local format. since I'm still a learner I'm bit new to this. can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand your question, if you don't need the id of log in the response.

you can simply do it as follows. by using **delete**

```
const array = [
  {
    id: "dsdsd",
    description: "test",
    duration: 60,
    date: "Mon Jan 01 1990",
  },
  {
    id: "abcd",
    description: "test",
    duration: 60,
    date: "Mon Jan 01 1990",
  },
];

const newArray = array.map(function (item) {
  delete item.id;
  return item;
});
console.log(newArray);
```

result of this would be,

```
[
  { description: 'test', duration: 60, date: 'Mon Jan 01 1990' },
  { description: 'test', duration: 60, date: 'Mon Jan 01 1990' }
]
```

so binding all together we can do it like this.

```
app.get("/api/users/:_id/logs", (req, res) => {
  let _id = req.params._id;
  User.findById(_id, (err, data) => {
    if (!err) {
      data.count = data.logs.length;

      const modifiedLogs = data.logs.map(function (item) {
        delete item.id;
        return item;
      });
      res.json({
        username: data.username,
        _id: data._id,
        count: data.count,
        log: modifiedLogs,
      });
    }
  });
});
```

*** note that. there may be many other ways.